# How do I run/debug a single .java file in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a simple java file as follows, which prints to the console:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.lang.Math.*;

public class CodingPrep {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello World");

    }
}
```

I'm trying to run this file via IntelliJ, WITHOUT creating any project, etc. (There is a reason for this however it's beyond the discussion here). How can I do that ?

So far I've just installed IntelliJ and have linked a Java JDK with it. When I try to run or debug this file, I get re-routed to the Edit Configurations Box, where there's an error showing: **"No module specified"**.

[image]
Note that my code is actually more than just a "Hello World", however it's all command prompt based, where I have to pass arguments to my calls to the executable, and also have to provide input (via `ReadLine`) while the program is running.

I need an IDE so that I can debug my java files using breakpoints, etc.

What do I do ?

Comment: When compiling a single java file from the command prompt, no "project" is required and the compiler just generates a simple class file. Why can't the same be done here ? Why is a "project" required ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with IDEA, because in order to run a class it needs some basic configuration, like JDK, classpath, output path etc.

So you must create and configure a module and put the class file in it. 
Then, when running it, a command prompt terminal will be opened in the IDE itself allowing you to enter the input.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error: **"No module specified"**. Write the name of your class in text box next to **Main class** in opened `Edit Configuration` window.

Here, you put **CodingPrep** in text box next to **Main class:** in opened `Edit Configuration` window.

It will work like charm.

Comment: Om, I have the exact same issue as the author of this post. Your solution unfortunately does not work -- when I start typing the name of the class it says "Can not resolve symbol"... is there any other way to solve that issue?

Comment: @Rotkiv, By *write name of your class in text box next to **Main class***, I meant the name of class having `main()` method.

Comment: sadly that does not seem to work for me, unless I am still missing your point.
https://prnt.sc/gooeue

Answer (score 0):

If you already have some other project opened then by default new single java file will be treated as part of existing project.

> To run single java file (CodingPrep.java in your case), you have to open the Edit Configuration and there, add a new configuration for Java Scratch, where you provide the below items:

- path to scratch file (`/home/user/path/to/CodingPrep.java`)
- Main class (`CodingPrep.java`)
- Working Directory
- Additionally you can save this config with name `CodingPrep` or any other name.

Apply and Save and you are good to go.
[Check the sample Edit Configuration here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f0Ju.jpg)

But since you do not have any project/do not want any project, you can use the Scratch files feature of IntelliJ. This assumes you have your code in a single `.java` file
You can use the scratch file in the following way:

- Open your file using IntelliJ launch screen via **Open** option
- Create a new scratch file like below
  [Create new scratch file in intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY6A8.png)
- Select it to be Java scratch file, which will make a main class by name `scratch.java`.
- Paste content of your file in this scratch file and this will be independently runnable.